# How to calculate average with calculation two times in PowerBI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, calculated-columns

I would like to calculate an average of a row with some condition. I tried this way:

```
AVG = SWITCH(
    TRUE()
    ,'Backlog items'[ORU]<>"X", 'Backlog items'[Close Date]=TRUE(), (CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Backlog items'[SCO]))))
```

The condition are, if `ORU` column is not equal to `X`, and `Close Date` is not empty, then calculate the average of `SCO` row.

When I tried that way above, it return this message

```
A circular dependency was detected: Backlog items[AVG], Backlog items[SC SCO], Backlog items[AVG].
```

Anyone can help me to have an idea about this.
I really appreciate for the help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your SWITCH Syntax is wrong, see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dax/switch-function-dax